# getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) but for LocationClient

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) returns a LocationManager.

I want the same functionality but for com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: why do you want to do so?

Comment: Because I am writing a BroadcastReceiver to handle a broadcast Intent and I want this BroadcastReceiver to use the same LocationClient instance each time it is called.

Comment: why do you need that instance?? actually, `LocationClient` has been created in your `Activity` and if you broadcast that object,ultimately you are going to keep the context in memory,so it will lead to memory leak.kindly describe your task in detail so that we can suggest you better approach

Comment: I am not broadcasting that object.

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does something like this exist?

You do not obtain a `LocationClient` via `getSystemService()`. You obtain a `LocationClient` via the `LocationClient` constructor.

> Because I am writing a BroadcastReceiver to handle a broadcast Intent and I want this BroadcastReceiver to use the same LocationClient instance each time it is called.

If your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via `registerReceiver()`, you are welcome to hold onto the instance of `LocationClient` for as long as the hosting component (activity or service) is active.

If your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, your process can be terminated between broadcasts, and so there is no means for you to ensure that you get the same `LocationClient` instance.

Comment: "If your BroadcastReceiver is registered in the manifest, your process can be terminated between broadcasts, and so there is no means for you to ensure that you get the same LocationClient instance." - so there would be an advantage to using LocationManager in this case

Comment: Thanks for explaining so well, by the way

Comment: @cja: "so there would be an advantage to using LocationManager in this case" -- no. No objects are the same in separate processes. "Is there a mechanism in Android that I can use for keeping instances between BroadcastReceiver " -- not across processes.

Comment: I don't want to use LocationClient in my BroadcastReceiver. Instead I want to use it in an activity. The activity will request location updates via pending intents, which will be handled by my BroadcastReceiver. The BroadcastReceiver won't use the LocationClient.

Comment: Thing is, the first activity may die, and I still want to be able to start another and stop location updates.

Comment: @cja: If you are using `PendingIntents`, you are clearly looking to receive location updates even if your process gets terminated. You do not need the same instance of `LocationClient` to "be able to start another and stop location updates".

Comment: Ok. In that case I am operating under a misunderstanding :)

Comment: To stop receiving updates, don't I need to call removeLocationUpdates on the same LocationClient instance on which I called requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: @cja: Certainly not for the `PendingIntent` scenario. The primary reason to use `PendingIntents` is because you expect to have different processes between location updates, and then it is impossible to have the same `LocationClient` instance.

Comment: So I can use a different LocationClient instance and the remove call will correspond to the request call? How does this work inside the LocationClient class?

Comment: @cja: "How does this work inside the LocationClient class?" -- it's closed source, so you will need to get a job at Google and ask them. "So I can use a different LocationClient instance and the remove call will correspond to the request call?" -- yes. You have to pass in an equivalent `PendingIntent`, where by "equivalent" I mean that it is the same type (activity, service, broadcast) and the underlying `Intent` is equivalent (same component, same action, same categories, same `Uri`, same MIME type). Presumably, they use a `HashMap` or something along those lines to hold onto these.

Comment: I'm not doubting you but (!) do you have a link to documentation on this behaviour?

Comment: @cja: The documentation for `LocationClient` is: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html

Comment: Thanks for explaining so thoroughly